# Fonts look ugly in Kubuntu 12.04 after setting resolution to 1440x900

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, fonts

I'm currently using Kubuntu 12.04 and after installing nVidia drivers and Setting resolution up to 1440x900 limit, fonts look ugly,only browser content fonts work well, I tried fixing them using Fonts-KDE contol Module, but it didn't work, Please help  here is a screenshot [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open KDE Settings Manager
2. Then go to **Application Appearence**
3. Select **Fonts** section
4. change the **Use anti-alialising** option to **Enabled**
5. Then click **Configure** button.
6. In the new window, select **Use subpixel-rendering** and change the value to **RGB**
7. Change the **hinting style** to **Slight**.
8. Then remove the file `.fonts.conf` in your home folder. It is a hidden file. To see, that file in Kubuntu, Press `Alt` + `.` .

   Here is a screenshot of the settings window

   [image]
9. Logout and Login again.

Comment: That helped, but Helvetica and Roboto (default fonts in G+ and Facebook) still look like a dog's breakfast.

Comment: Oh never mind, I had the "Exclude Range" checked. Unchecking that fixed everything!

Comment: Holy crap did that ever improve things.

Answer (score 0):

In your home folder, rename .fonts.conf to .fonts.conf.bak then log out. Log back in and the fonts in Firefox are good to go.